# I want to print keys in a dictionary from class

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to print planets name which are stored as a key in the dictionary, However I am getting nothing at all, just space

this is my code:

```
class planets:
    def __init__(self, aDict):
        self.aDict = aDict
    def __str__(self):
        for key in self.aDict.keys():
            print(key)



aDict = {"Sun": 1000, "Mercury": 10, "Earth": 60, "Mars": 50, "jupiter": 100}
p = planets(aDict)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually print `p` and __str__ needs to return a string, e.g.:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(sorted(self.aDict, key=self.aDict.get))

aDict = {"Sun": 1000, "Mercury": 10, "Earth": 60, "Mars": 50, "jupiter": 100}
p = planets(aDict)
print(p)
```

Comment: Why is it printing them in a random order ?  is there a way to make it print by value order ?

Comment: You can also use `return '\n'.join(sorted(self.aDict, key=self.aDict.get))`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `p.__str__()` at the last.

```
class planets:
    def __init__(self, aDict):
        self.aDict = aDict
    def __str__(self):
        for key in self.aDict:
            print(key)



aDict = {"Sun": 1000, "Mercury": 10, "Earth": 60, "Mars": 50, "jupiter": 100}
p = planets(aDict)
p.__str__()
```

**Output:**

```
Mercury
Sun
Mars
jupiter
Earth
```

Comment: `for key in self.aDict:` would be more appropriate

Comment: _\_str__ is used by python print function, calling it directly and not honouring the standard definition of _\_str__ is probably not a great idea

Comment: @achampion it's not the great idea but it also does the same job as print does.

Answer (score 0):

The `__str__` "magic method" should `return` a string rather than doing any printing itself. Having such a method that doesn't `return` a string generates an error. Use that method to build up a string, then return that string. You can then call that method "magically" with `print(p)`. For example:

```
>>> aDict = {"Sun": 1000, "Mercury": 10, "Earth": 60, "Mars": 50, "jupiter": 100}
>>> class planets(object):
...     def __init__(self, aDict):
...         self.aDict = aDict
...     def __str__(self):
...         return '\n'.join(self.aDict)
...
>>> print(planets(aDict))
Mercury
Sun
Earth
Mars
jupiter
```